# How to encrypt messages/text with RSA & OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have Alice's public key. I want to send Alice an RSA encrypted message.
How can I do it using the `openssl` command?

The message is:

> Hi Alice! Please bring malacpörkölt for dinner!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the [openssl manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html) (`openssl` man page), search for `RSA`, and you'll see that the command for RSA encryption is `rsautl`. Then read the [`rsautl` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/rsautl.html) to see its syntax.

```
echo 'Hi Alice! Please bring malacpörkölt for dinner!' |
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey alice.pub >message.encrypted
```

The default [padding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Padding_schemes) is the original PKCS#1 v1.5 (still used in many procotols); openssl also supports OAEP (now recommended) and raw encryption (only useful in special circumstances).

Note that using openssl directly is mostly an exercise. In practice, you'd use a tool such as [gpg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) (which uses RSA, but not directly to encrypt the message).

Comment: What's the issue with using`openssl`?

Comment: @Bratchley The `openssl` command line tool is a mixture of different commands. Some, mostly the ones that manipulate certificates, can be useful, but are hard to use correctly because their syntax and parameters are quirky. Some, like `rsautl`, are fine but don't provide useful functionality, they just expose raw cryptographic primitives — for example RSA encryption is pretty much only used to encrypt a symmetric key for hybrid encryption. Some, like `enc`, are very hard to use securely and the world would be better off if they didn't exist.

Comment: Great answer. I added padding with this flag -oaep

Then on decrypt, specify the same...

openssl rsautl -decrypt -in message.encrypted -inkey private_key.pem -oaep

Comment: "The command rsautl was deprecated in version 3.0. Use 'pkeyutl' instead. "

Answer (score 30):

First, if you just want good encryption, you should look at [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html).  But if your experimenting and just want to learn how it works, you need to understand what [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) is.  RSA isn't designed to encrypt any arbitrary string, it's an algorithm that encrypts an integer.  Specifically, an integer from 0 to n-1 where n is the modulus value from the public key.  When you talk about a RSA key that's 1024 bits, that means it takes 1024 bits to store the modulus in binary.  This is one of the reasons, RSA is used in combination with a symmetric key cipher like [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) or [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).  You can generate a random 256 bit key for AES and encrypt that key with a 1024 bit RSA public key.  Then anyone which access to the private key can extract the symmetric key and decode the message with AES.  The full standard for RSA is called [PKCS #1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017)

Furthermore, DES and AES are block ciphers.  They only encrypt data in block of a specific size.  DES uses 64-bit blocks and AES uses 128-bit blocks.  To encrypt more than a block, you must use a [Mode of Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_of_operation) like CBC or CTR.  These modes specify how to encrypt a stream of bits using a block mode cipher.

Lastly, it's important to verify the data you are receiving.  While an attacker may not be able to read data in transit, he may be able to flip bits without detection if no integrity or authenticity is applied to the data stream.  An attacker can easily guess that an SSL connection to port 443 is probably a webpage request starting with `GET /` and he could flip bit changing it to `PUT /` without interfering with the rest of the encryption.  A simple approach to integrity is to append an MD5 or SHA-1 sum at the end, but that only provides data integrity, not data authenticity.  Any one with complete knowledge of the data stream can generate a correct sum, a more secure approach is to use a keyed-hash like [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) which requires knowledge of a secret key to generate thereby providing data authenticity in addition to integrity.

Comment: This is really good

Answer (score 6):

In the below, note you can specify whatever algorithm you want, be it the ones listed or RSA (though I do not know the exact name used for RSA by OpenSSL)

use "openssl enc -help" to get a list of supported ciphers on your system, and pass that as an argument. eg, "-aes256"

Note on my system I do not have RSA in my options - at least by that name.

---

How do I encrypt a S/MIME message?

Let’s say that someone sends you her public certificate and asks that you encrypt some message to her. You’ve saved her certificate as her-cert.pem. You’ve saved your reply as my-message.txt.

To get the default—though fairly weak—RC2-40 encryption, you just tell openssl where the message and the certificate are located.

> openssl smime her-cert.pem -encrypt -in my-message.txt

If you’re pretty sure your remote correspondent has a robust SSL toolkit, you can specify a stronger encryption algorithm like triple DES:

> openssl smime her-cert.pem -encrypt -des3 -in my-message.txt

By default, the encrypted message, including the mail headers, is sent to standard output. Use the -out option or your shell to redirect it to a file. Or, much trickier, pipe the output directly to sendmail.

```
openssl smime her-cert.pem \
   -encrypt \
   -des3 \
   -in my-message.txt \
   -from 'Your Fullname <you@youraddress.com>' \
   -to 'Her Fullname <her@heraddress.com>' \
   -subject 'My encrypted reply' |\
 sendmail her@heraddress.com
```

How do I sign a S/MIME message?

If you don’t need to encrypt the entire message, but you do want to sign it so that your recipient can be assured of the message’s integrity, the recipe is similar to that for encryption. The main difference is that you need to have your own key and certificate, since you can’t sign anything with the recipient’s cert.

```
 openssl smime \
   -sign \
   -signer /path/to/your-cert.pem \
   -in my-message.txt \
   -from 'Your Fullname <you@youraddress.com>' \
   -to 'Her Fullname <her@heraddress.com>' \
   -subject 'My signed reply' |\
 sendmail her@heraddress.com
```

---

(from http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/ )

(er... all those backslashes - those are supposed to be escaped newlines. not sure what's going on, as it displays fine in my edit box here!

Comment: You need to put four spaces at the start of each line to preserve newlines.  I changed the first block to show you how.  Can you fix the second?

Comment: You didn't find RSA in `openssl enc` because `enc` is for symmetric encryption only. Yeah, openssl's options aren't very well organized. Asymetric algorithms have their own commands: `rsa`/`dsa`/`dh` to manipulate keys, `rsautl`/`dsautl` to encrypt/decrypt/verify/sign, and `genrsa`/`gendsa`/`gendh` to generate keys.